# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency "messages"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webhooks, mern

I am trying to use MERN for the first time but now I am stuck with this code that returns the above mentioned warning and though the compilation works but some activities are missing. I am attaching my part of the code along with this.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Chat from "./Chat";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
import axios from './axios'

function App() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])

  useEffect(() =>{
    axios.get('/messages/sync').then((response) => {
      setMessages(response.data)
    })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const pusher = new Pusher('----------------', {
      cluster: '^^^'
    });

    const channel = pusher.subscribe('message');
    channel.bind('inserted',(newMessage) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(newMessage));
      setMessages([...messages, newMessage])
    });
  }, [])

  console.log(messages)

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="app_body">
        <Sidebar />
        <Chat />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the console output:

```
Compiled with warnings.

./src/App.js
  Line 27:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'messages'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setMessages(m => ...)' if you only need 'messages' in the 'setMessages' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

I am trying to build this app with a online video tutorial but this is the problem that occurs to me. How to fix this issue?

Comment: If you add `messages` in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook, your code will get stuck in an infinite cycle of state update and re-render. To avoid adding `messages` in the dependency array, change `setMessages([...messages, newMessage])` to `setMessages(currentMsgs => [...currentMsgs, newMessage])`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using state `messages` in `useEffect`. You just using function when call `setMessages` to update state like this:

```
setMessages(preMessages => ([...preMessages , newMessage]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the current existing answers explain why this is necessary.

The `useEffect` hook can be run in 3 scenarios:

- `useEffect(fn)` is run every time your component renders
- `useEffect(fn, [])` is run the first time your component mounts
- `useEffect(fn, [var1, var2])` is run initially, and then any time either `var1` or `var2` changes.

The reason you are getting the warning is that the linter has detected you are using an outside dependency (`messages`) in your function, however it's not listed as an explicit dependency. As such, if `messages` were to change, the `useEffect` would have a stale version and it would likely cause bugs.

Comment: The outside dependency is `messages`. `setMessage` wont be a problem as it is guaranteed to be stable.